# SwiftUI - How to remove huge space on left of List while editing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

To enable rearranging items in my `List`, I added an `EditButton()` and attached the `onMove` modifier. Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var names = ["Adam", "Bob", "Cole", "Dad", "Ella"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .onMove { names.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1) }
            }
            .toolbar { EditButton() }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I press the "Edit" button, I can reorder the items. However, a huge space appears on the left side of each row.

| Not editing | Edit button pressed |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Names stacked vertically, Edit button inside navigation bar] | [image: Names stacked vertically with huge space on left, Done button inside navigation bar] |

How do I get rid this space?

<sup>I suspect that it's placeholder space for a delete button, but I don't need a delete button.</sup>